# UWP TreeView sorting items

Tags: sorting, data-binding, uwp, treeview, items

How can I sort items in databinded UWP TreeView? ItemsSource of UWP TreeView is binded to observable collection in View Model. IS there a way to create a view for collection that TreeView is binded to, similar to WPF? Currenlty I'm out of options how can I implement this feature and I'm new to UWP.

Comment: Hello, for your question, you can view this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view), which describes in detail how to use TreeView. You can use DataTemplate to create a view for TreeView. If the documentation does not solve your problem, please elaborate on the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @Richasy had read that document multiple times before. It does mention DataTemplates in regard of templating individual items. However, there is no mention how can I sort ALL items in the TreeView based on some criteria (for example, name).

Comment: Sorting should be done for the data. Since you are using DataBinding, sort the collection. If you are confused, I can provide a simple sorting example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need the children collection of each TreeViewNode.Content to be sorted (TreeViewNode.Content will be one of the elements of your collection). You also need to bind the ItemSource of each TreeViewItem to the children collection of the element that supplies the Content; you can do this using Bind in the TreeViewItem data template).

Are you using EF, maybe EF Core? If so then a few notes.  The default navigation collection in EF Core is a Hashset, so you must assign an ordered collection instead such as observable collection. Also, EF will use Add to add to the child collections, and not necessarily in the order that you want it to. So you need to override the Add method in your collection to make insert in sorted order.

Comment: This should be a good answer if in fact the children nodes existed below the root level. This causes me real problems because nodes cannot be selected visually programmatically below the second level.